# Extra space next to menu?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that spans across the page. I have its wrapper set to 100% and correctly, it spans completely across its container. I have for menu items set at 25% each however, there is around 20px space to the left of the menu revealing the background color. Regardless of sizes and margin:0 auto, the space remains.

```css
.center{
 margin:0 auto; 
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#3c87bc;
 padding:0;
}


#top_forums_menu{
 width:100%;
 height:24px;
 background-color:#5dbcff;
 position:relative;
}


ul#top_forums_menu_bars {
    list-style-type: none;
   margin:0 auto;

}
ul#top_forums_menu_bars li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
 
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;

  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li:hover{
 border-bottom:5px solid #3a5871;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 opacity:1;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
 line-height:10px;
 padding-top:7px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 color:white;


 
}
ul#top_forums_menu_bars li a:hover {
 opacity:.8;
 
}
```

```html
<div id='top_forums_menu'>
<div class='center'>
 <ul id='top_forums_menu_bars'>
 <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>Profile</a></li>
 <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>Account Settings</a></li>
 <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>My Content</a></li>
 <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>MyOACH</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the left-padding

```
ul#top_forums_menu_bars {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36ywxtyk/4/

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` has a default padding which can be removed with the following rule:

```
ul#top_forums_menu_bars
{
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<ul>` elements (along with `<menu>` and `<dir>` elements have a built-in browser rendering of `padding-start: 40px`. This is what is causing the offset that you see.

The easiest way to resolve this is to explicitly give your `ul#top_forums_menu_bars` a `padding` of `0`, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3c87bc;
  padding: 0;
}

#top_forums_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #5dbcff;
  position: relative;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -4px black;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #3a5871;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}

ul#top_forums_menu_bars li a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div id='top_forums_menu'>
  <div class='center'>
    <ul id='top_forums_menu_bars'>
      <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>Account Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>My Content</a></li>
      <li><a href='' style='background-color:#5dbcff;'>MyOACH</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could apply a **global** low-**[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** rule of:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will override all of the browser padding / margin quirks, while still having a low enough specificity for any individual selectors to override these rules.